# Server A using xmlreader to read XML from xmlwriter on server B

Tags: php, timeout, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I have two servers

**Server A reads http://www.some-url.com/xmlwriter_src.php using**

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('http://www.some-url.com/xmlwriter_src.php');
while ($reader->read()) 
{
  /* -- do something -- */
}
```

**Server B creates an xml stream**

```
$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openURI('php://output');
$writer->startDocument("1.0");

$writer->startElement("records");
while(!$recordset->EOF)
{
  $writer->startElement($fieldname) 
  $writer->text($recordset->fields[$fieldname]);
  $writer->endElement();
  $recordset->movenext();
}
```

the xmlreader on server A keeps complaining that server B doesnt respond, even though I can see the xml result in the browser.

It takes less than a second to generate

If i copy the xml to a static file, the xmlreader outputs the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the writter will buffer your output.
Once you are done you MUST call flush().

```
$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openURI('php://output');
$writer->startDocument("1.0");

$writer->startElement("records");
while(!$recordset->EOF)
{
  $writer->startElement($fieldname) 
  $writer->text($recordset->fields[$fieldname]);
  $writer->endElement();
  $recordset->movenext();
}
$writer->flush();
```

By the way:
 where do you close the records element?

Answer (score 1):

did u tried adding

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
```

Else the reader will consider it as simple text and wont work. Try giving that at the begining of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing whatever xmlReader reads on the disk and inspect the generated file. I have a hunch its either empty or invalid(incomplete) XML. 
If i'm right, then you might have a *timeout* that expires sooner than the one you get in a real browser. Either that, or a connection that requires either connection-close or keepalive(i've seen servers broken like this).

Also, make sure you dont have a firewall on the server where the client runs that might block the xmlReader from talking to the xmlWriter:) Try `iptables -L` in the server console to check any firewall rules.

---

Edit: you might also need to call something like `xmlReader->close()`, or `end()` or whatever member you got there that closes the connection and signals the client that the transmission is over.